# How can I add a toolbar button to start an .exe file from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The title is self explanatory.  I would like to add a button to a toolbar in order to run an external executable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the application as an "External Tool", using Tools... > External Tools.  Take note of where your entry was added to the list; on a stock vs2010, that would be entry #5.

Click the mini drop-down button on the right side of your toolbar and select Add or Remove Buttons > Customize...

Click Add Command..., select the Tools category on the left, then External Command N on the right, where N is the entry number from the External Tools dialog.

Comment: @Will I'm pretty sure it is 1-based.  Create GUID is External Command 1; there is no External Command 0.

Comment: Crapola.  You're right.  The "Install Web Components" (SP1?) command is inserted into the same group as [External Tools.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a3fb7.png).  So you need to count the tools as listed in the [External Tools dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b0JIx.png).  I fixed my comment.